# Can I use Dance Central 2 co-op mode with dance central songs?

Tags: dance-central-2, dance-central-3, dance-central

I just bought the original Dance Central game without realizing that you cannot really do co-op dance. I am wondering if I export the songs to Dance Central 2 or 3 if I will be able to use co-op for the songs on there?
Thanks!